# Variables disappear when making .txt's

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm writing a batch code that when prompted will write a `.bat` file. This is an example of the code I'm using to create the `.bat`:

```
echo set /a num=0 >>%fileinfo%.bat
echo :repeat1 >>%fileinfo%.bat
echo set /a num=%num% +1 >>%fileinfo%.bat
echo echo %num% >>%fileinfo%.bat
echo if %num%==100 goto end >>%fileinfo%.bat 
echo goto repeat1 >>%fileinfo%.bat
```

This is the original code:

```
set /a num=0
:repeat1
set /a num=%num% +1
echo %num%
if %num%==100 goto end
goto repeat1
```

What happens when I run the code and create the new .bat:

```
set /a num=0 
:repeat1 
set /a num= +1 
echo  
if ==100 goto end  
goto repeat1
```

It takes out the `%num%`, can anyone think of a way around this or an alternative method to create the file? Thanks.

Comment: In a few examples at this link http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/win32/win32scripting.html the author wraps the variables in "", does that change anything?

Comment: @pippin yes, but the change is subtle. `set "var=value"` ensures that any trailing spaces left on the line by your editor are **NOT** included in the value assigned. Also `set "var=value   "` will assign three trailing spaces after the string `value` and won't disappear if you editor helpfully drops trailing spaces on lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo set /a num=0 >>%fileinfo%.bat

echo :repeat1 >>%fileinfo%.bat

echo set /a num=%%num%% +1 >>%fileinfo%.bat

echo echo %%num%% >>%fileinfo%.bat

echo if %%num%%==100 goto end >>%fileinfo%.bat 

echo goto repeat1 >>%fileinfo%.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "fileinfo=q20296357x"
(
 echo set /a num=0
 echo :repeat1
 echo set /a num=%%num%% +1
 echo echo %%num%%
 echo if %%num%%==100 goto end
 echo goto repeat1 
)>>%fileinfo%.bat
TYPE %fileinfo%.bat 
GOTO :EOF
```

Your fundamental problem is that `%var%` is replaced by the CONTENTS of `var` before the line is executed. For some characters which have a special meaning to batch like the redirectors <kbd>></kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd><</kbd> you need to prefix the special character with <kbd>^</kbd>.

Bizarrely, to "escape" <kbd>%</kbd>, the escape charater is not <kbd>^</kbd> but <kbd>%</kbd> itself - so each literal <kbd>%</kbd> needs to be coded as <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>

Note how your code can be condensed by parenthesising the `ECHO`s and redirecting to your target file.

Note also that  you could also code `...goto :EOF` instead of `...goto end` if you actually want to go to the end-of-file. `eof` is a magic label - batch understands it to be end-of-file so it should not be declared in your batch. Case is not important, but the colon is required.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'll try this now. And I did :end because after this sequence it would skip down to a loop called :end